# Scala replaceAllIn not working correctly?

Tags: scala

In this context I am working with Scala version **2.12.10**. With the following regular expression

```
val regex = ",,".r
```

I call `replaceAllIn` on a given string `str`. The aim is to insert a blank between two commas.

```
val str = "a,b,,,,,,c,,d,e,,f"

val newstr = regex.replaceAllIn(str,", ,")
```

The result is unexpected:

```
newstr: String = a,b, ,, ,, ,c, ,d,e, ,f
```

I would have preferred:

```
newstr: String = a,b, , , , , ,c, ,d,e, ,f
```

Only running the same `replaceAllIn` a second time with `newstr` as input gives the expected result. Is this maybe a bug?

Comment: It looks like it does exactly what you are telling it to do: replacing 3 times ',,' with ', ,'. Nothing unexpected here.

Comment: In order to get the result you're expecting `replaceAllIn` would have to recursively apply its "find and replace" algorithm. I don't think that's how it works.

Comment: Yes indeed, I expected it to work recursively. As we can see it does not. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The doc at https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findAllIn(source:CharSequence):scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator explains:

> To return overlapping matches, it is possible to formulate a regular
>   expression with lookahead (?=) that does not consume the overlapping
>   region.

```
scala> val r = ",,".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = ,,

scala> val str = "a,b,,,,,,c,,d,e,,f"
str: String = a,b,,,,,,c,,d,e,,f

scala> val newstr = r.replaceAllIn(str,", ,")
newstr: String = a,b, ,, ,, ,c, ,d,e, ,f

scala> val r = "(,)(?=(,))".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (,)(?=(,))

scala> val newstr = r.replaceAllIn(str,", ,")
newstr: String = a,b, ,, ,, ,, ,, ,,c, ,,d,e, ,,f

scala> val newstr = r.replaceAllIn(str,", ")
newstr: String = a,b, , , , , ,c, ,d,e, ,f
```

Comment: This lookahead syntax looks promising and enlarges my knowledge about regular expressions. Thank you, as well!